# What is the different between 'Auto' and '*' when setting width/height for a grid column?

Tags: wpf, xaml

I cannot distinguish the different between `Auto` and `*` when setting `width` and `height` for a grid column.

Comment: Seems like you're talking about grid rows/columns... they're not actually elements.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is difference between " * " and "Auto" in Silverlight Grid Layout Definitions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2884625/what-is-difference-between-and-auto-in-silverlight-grid-layout-definition)

Comment: I know the duplicate I suggest is for Silverlight, but the syntax is the same for WPF.

Answer (score 291, accepted):

We're talking in the context of `WPF` Grid here? My answer will talk about columns, but the same applies to rows.

In brief:
- `Auto` means **size to column content** and
-  `*` means **size proportional to grid**

`Auto` means that a column is given as much width as the elements within it require. 
The width of `*` sized columns is calculated by allocating space for the `Auto`, and fixed width columns, and then dividing up the remaining space. So if there's only one `*` sized column, it will get all the remaining space, if there were two they would get half each, etc. You can also change the proportion allocated to each star sized column.

If column A had a size of `2*` and B had a size of `3*` then whole column space is divided into 5 equal shares; column A would get 2 shares of the space and B would get 3 shares.

Comment: Coming here for the third time in two years. I wish I could upvote once each time. :)

Comment: Fourth time, actually.

Comment: @Spotted same here, i can never remember this stuff :)